# UpdateView - different fields list for specific user type

Tags: python, django

I have UpdateView from CBV:

```
class AuthorUpdate(UpdateView):
        model = Author
        fields = ['name']
```

How can I set different fields list for specific user type?

For example:

```
if request.user.pk == 1:
    fields = ['name', 'job', ]
else:
    fields = ['name', 'title', ]
```

Where can I override this?

Comment: Just set the model to the specific one? i'm not sure theres enough information here to answer

Comment: are you trying to check if the user is staff or a super user?

Comment: @GeorginaS no, I'm trying to display different fields in form for specific user type or depending of other object value(this is not important).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option to do this would be to define two different form classes, then override [`get_form_class`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.get_form_class). You can access the user with `self.request.user`, then return the appropriate form class.

```
class JobForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ['name', 'job']

class TitleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = ['name', 'title']

class AuthorUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Author

    def get_form_class(self):
        if self.request.user.pk == 1:
            return JobForm
        else:
            return TitleForm
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to set the fields based on your condition like so;

```
def get_form_class(self):
    if condition1:
       self.fields = ['field1', 'field2]
    else:
       self.fields = ['field3', 'field4']
    return super().get_form_class()
```